# Windows deleted a folder without asking or confirmation

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, usb

I have an USB drive, that I use for copying files from my Windows 7-based computer to my Linux-based home theather system. Media Player creates `.Theater` folder in disk's root folder, every time disk is connected to it. It contains some player's internals. I noticed absolutely no problems, when folder is gone.

Today, I have connected USB disk to my PC to copy some more media and a standard dialog pop, asking me, if I want to scan the disk before using it. It is nearly always displayed, when disk contains that `.Theater` folder. I clicked `No` and I have immediately noticed, that **Windows deleted this folder**!

What is going on or what am I missing? How can Windows delete any user folder without asking him/her for an confirmation of such operation. Especially, taking into account, that this is external disk, so deleted folders are not recycled, but gone "for good" (until using USB recovery tools).

I recall, that Windows, even up until newest versions, gets completely wako about files or folders without name (only with extension). But, this is something new and something what causes me to have a real concerns about safety of my files.

Comment: I can has (contain) anything it or I want. That is not a point. Window **can't** delete any user file, without asking me for a permission to do so. That's a point.

Comment: I had to struggle a little to understand what you wrote, so I hope I got it right. 1. Can you reproduce the problem? 2. When you say 'Media Player' you mean the Linux-based and not the Microsoft one, right? 3. I understand that Windows never deleted anything this way before - what have changed in your system? (updates, utilities, etc.)

Comment: @EliadTech I hope I was better in explaining this! :> 1. This happened for me only once so far. 2. Yes, Media Player = Linux-based external device. 3. = 1. I have never experienced anything like that before. 4. Nothing, that I'm aware of (neither software nor hardware) has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing the same steps (loading the files to the USB, plugging it to the media player, etc.), and see if it happens again.
If the problem doesn't recur so this might be a one-time slip (As you wrote, it never happened before).

If it does happen again, try using an earlier (meaning before the first time it occurred) restore point.
If it happens again after using the restore point, then try again using a different computer.
Also, try reformatting the USB and running chkdsk on it afterwards - maybe he has some bad sectors.

Comment: I'm picking your answer, as the one containing many useful tips for a quite wide area of problem, such as my question is (after all). I assume, that the answer to my (maybe not directly expressed) question: "_Can Windows delete user file without confirmation?_" is: "_No!_" in your opinion. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, OS should never delete files without a warning.

Comment: Just to provide more detail -- this is a repeatable situation. The `.Theater` folder gets removed by my Windows 7 everytime I connect external drive to computer and refuse to scan the "damaged" disk. I'm not sure if this wasn't happening in the past or if I simply didn't noticed this fact?

Comment: Can you test with a newly installed computer? can you reformat the USB (preferably using Diskpart Clean)?

Comment: Since this isn't actually a problem for me (media player can work without this folder and will always recreate it, if it is missing), so lets just assume, that my question was purely to feed my curiosity and lets just pass it now. I don't want to make this into a chat or forum discussion. Eventually, problem looks limited only to my case. Thanks for all your efforts.